# Apple Pay on Web and Shipping cost calculation

Tags: applepay, applepayjs, applepay-web

Trying to see if other have faced the similar issue. we are trying to integrate Apple Pay checkout on our store and it seems to be working fine except one major issues. Here are some additional pointer.

1. We use external service to give us the shipping cost based on the address and shipment weight.
2. As per the service documentation, they need address line1 along with city, postal code etc. to provide the accurate cost (e.g. residential address might add surcharges etc.).
3. Since Apple Pay will not provide full ship to address until customer have approved the transaction, we have seen some cases where the final shipping amount calculated by service is more than what was initially calculated based on limited address.

I am sure, we are not the only one who are facing this scenario. Can anyone help with the following queries?

1. If you have faced this issue, what was the solution to handle this difference?
2. Is there any other option to handle this?

One suggestion which I have seen in few forum is to recalculate the final shipping price once we have the full address from Apple Pay and use that for final auth, however I have few question on that

1. Not sure if this will work (Need to do some POC for sure), but I assume Apple auth event will have information on the final amount that was approved by customer.
2. If if #1 work, I am not sure if this is a good customer experience, as I might see different amount during the auth and on the confirmation page.

Any suggestion or pointer will really be helpful

Comment: Probably not a good question for SO, but charge everyone worst case scenario shipping cost if your margins are that thin.

Comment: @mxmissile I agree, its more of the abstract question but have not seen any answer on any forum :)